# Linq to Sql - Manual association with manual parameter

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following tables in my database:

**SageAccount**

- ID (bigint)
- LegacyID (nvarchar)
- Customer (bit)

**Consignments**

- ID (bigint)
- Customer (nvarchar)

What I want to do is have a navigation property/association in my Linq to Sql dbml from `Consignment` to `SageAccount`. The difficulty with this is that not only do we need to match `SageAccount.LegacyID => Consignments.Customer` but we also need to only join to sage accounts where SageAccount.Customer is TRUE. So on the Consignments end, it isn't joining onto a field but instead a static value.

Is this possible in Linq to Sql? Note this database doesn't (and unfortunately can't) have any foreign keys setup in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. linq have `join` method. You can use it ike this in your situation:

```
var res = from sageAccount in _context.SageAccount
            join consignments in _context.Consignments
            on
            new
            {
                LegacyID = sageAccount.LegacyID,
                Customer = sageAccount.Customer
            }
            equals
            new
            {
                LegacyID = consignments.ID,
                Customer = true
            }
            select new { SageAccountID = sageAccount.ID };
```

**Note that Property name, Type and order in the anonymous objects that you're joining on must match.**

You can't use `OR` and `AND` in joins - use just `equals` one object to other.

This will have a this kind of result in your SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[ID] AS [SageAccountID]
FROM [dbo].[SageAccount] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Consignments] AS [t1] ON (([t0].[LegacyID]) = [t1].[ID]) 
                                        AND ([t0].[Customer] = 1)
```